# IoT Edge offline capabilities (not extended)

Tags: azure-iot-edge

A question on IoT Edge offline capabilities (not extended).
After IoT Edge was connected at least once to IoT Hub, will it continue to function with **no** connection **between restarts** (module to module communication)?
If yes, for how long (certificate lifetime etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can work indefinitely offline until (as you correctly point out) certificate lifetime.

Another thing to be aware of (as of release 1.0.8) is that either cached module container instances are present, which means "docker start modulex" operation is possible or if an image pull is needed, there is access to the container registry when offline.